# Intellij: JVM remote debug no log showing upon process startup and intellij and not stopping at breakpoint (Connection Prematurilly closed)

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

I am remote trying to establish remote debugging after ssh tunneling on PORT 9045 of my remote dev server. However even though I am able to access `http://localhost:9045` in my machine, my JVM debugger would just not start.

Here's my Debugger config:
[image]

Upon running debug, I get this:
[image]

And after a minute or so, I get this message:
[image: Connection PreMaturely Closed]

Can anyone help me understand what is possibly going wrong here? I have tested hitting local nedpoint in my machine to make sure connection is established on port 9045.

Comment: Have you checked idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")? Are any additional errors recorded there? Please check that AV or firewall don't block java connections.